# How do you write to a HTML element from Mongoose with Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

For example, I'm using a form to display all info from the DB:

```
<form action="/Userlist" method="get">
      <input type="submit" value="Get All">
    </form>
  <P>
    Should go here
  </P>
```

This is served just fine by a get request:

```
app.get('/userlist' , function (req , res) {
    User.find({}, 'comment').then(function (users) {
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

But it is just a static page. 
How can I write the result from Mongoose to for example a HTML

tag - such that all comments are async displayed on the landing page?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackOverflow.
Please follow some good tutorials before asking here, tons out there.
Just Google CRUD in node.js & mongodb.
For your problem, you need to render the page instead of returning json.

```
res.render('index.ejs', {users})
```

instead of  `res.json(users);` & the html should be `.ejs`
This looks like a nice tutorial to start https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX for the get request somewhere inside you static html page in a `script` tag.

Below is an example of how to do this.

```js
$.get("http://localhost:8080/userlist", function(users){
   var i;
    for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      $( "p" ).append( "<div>" + users[i] + "</div>" );
    }
});
```